# Unable to rename a foreign column in laravel 5.8 - column not found error

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to rename a foreign column. So I write the following code:

```
Schema::table('floor_plans', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropForeign(['unit_type_id']);
    $table->renameColumn('unit_type_id', 'utd_id');
    $table->foreign('utd_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('unit_type_details')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

But it throws

```
   Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException  : There is no column with name 'unit_type_id ' on table 'floor_plans'.

  at D:\wamp64\www\amenity\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException.php:85
    81|      * @return \Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException
    82|      */
    83|     public static function columnDoesNotExist($columnName, $table)
    84|     {
  > 85|         return new self(
    86|             sprintf("There is no column with name '%s' on table '%s'.", $columnName, $table),
    87|             self::COLUMN_DOESNT_EXIST
    88|         );
    89|     }
```

Then I tried by turning foreign checks off:

```
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');
$table->dropForeign(['unit_type_id']);
$table->renameColumn('unit_type_id ', 'utd_id');
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1');
```

But same error, the column not found.

Then I tried to drop foreign with exact ForeignKeyConstraint as :

```
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');
$table->dropForeign('floor_plans_unit_type_id_foreign');
$table->renameColumn('unit_type_id', 'utd_id');
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1');
$table->foreign('utd_id')
    ->references('id')
    ->on('unit_type_details')
    ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Still the same error.
I then even tried with Raw SQL as:

```
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE floor_plans
DROP FOREIGN KEY `floor_plans_unit_type_id_foreign`,
ADD CONSTRAINT `floor_plans_unit_type_detail_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`unit_type_detail_id`) REFERENCES `unit_type_details` (`id`)");
```

And this gives me the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'floor_plans_unit_type_id_foreign'; check that column/key exists (SQL: ALTER TABLE floor_plans
DROP FOREIGN KEY `floor_plans_unit_type_id_foreign`,
ADD CONSTRAINT `floor_plans_unit_type_detail_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`unit_type_detail_id`) REFERENCES `unit_type_details` (`id`))
```

And here is the screenshot of the table.
[image]

All I want is to rename `unit_type_id` to `unit_type_detail_id`.

#PS: the table is not empty. And, I am happy to run even if you provide me the raw MySQL query.

Comment: verify once your `.env`  file, to ensure which database ur using

Comment: I am using the correct database. I have even tried using `clear:cache` and `config:cache`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Their is an additional space on unit_type_id.

```php
Schema::table('floor_plans', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropForeign(['unit_type_id']);//note foreign key already dropped so also you have to make this line also as comment when you test.  
    //$table->renameColumn('unit_type_id ', 'utd_id');//remove this space and try again
    $table->renameColumn('unit_type_id', 'utd_id');//after remove space 
    $table->foreign('utd_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('unit_type_details')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Comment: Questions that are the result of typographical errors, or are otherwise not reproducible, are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Instead of answering, leave a comment pointing out the error, and then flag the question for closure as off-topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot @miken32 to inform me. I didn't know this before.
i have to delete my answer ? and add comment ? or skip it.

Comment: I would suggest deleting, yes. You will get back rep and the question will disappear faster if it’s unanswered

Comment: @anasomush thank you for highlighting it. I don't know who downvoted your answer.